# Duplicate column name in "insert...where not exists" statement

Tags: mysql

The following is part of a larger database patch concerning a table in which roleplay characters are linked to their skills. What I want is that from now on, not only skills they have are in there, but also skills they don't have (with count 0) and those they must not have (count -1).

```
insert into char2skill select * from 
(select null, 23, 23, -1, '') as foo where not exists 
(select * from char2skill where `char`=23 and skill=23);
```

The script crashes on this line (character #23 is linked to skill #23 here), saying

*1060 - Duplicate column name '23'*

I guess it's the nested select statement I use to define the values that should be inserted, but I don't know how to fix it...?

MySQL version is 5.0.51a

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make that `... (select null AS a, 23 AS b, 23 AS c, -1 AS d, '' AS e) ...`

Comment: Thank you so much! I was thinking too complicated, it seems... ;)

Answer (score 0):

try add some fnurrps "`" around skill

```
insert into char2skill select * from 
(select null, 23, 23, -1, '') as foo where not exists 
(select * from char2skill where `char`=23 and  `skill`=23);
```

Comment: It works without these symbols while "char" alone throws an error - is it bad coding style to leave the thingies away when they aren't really needed?